# Bearer token authentication with cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, bearer-token, authorize-attribute, cookie-authentication

I want to use Cookie for storing bearer token in my asp.net mvc application and I want that Cookie will be checked per request for client authentication (I don't want to add *"Autentication"* header for each request on the front-end).
How can I implement it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a cookie provider to handle Authorization. Check this
https://alexdunn.org/2017/03/31/asp-net-tips-consuming-bearer-tokens-as-a-cookie/